# What does "苦しいのか気持ちいのかわからん" mean?

Tags: translation

Found it on twitter. https://twitter.com/sarukiwa/status/1157194758961299457/video/1

My literal interpretation comes to "I don't know what feels good or bad."
Why would the fish be saying that? What exactly does the phrase mean?

Answer (score 3):

I would translate the original tweet like this:

> このアザラシ、苦しいのか気持ちいのかわからんWWWWWWWW
>   This seal... Not sure whether it is suffering from pain or just feeling good? LOL

The context: The 18-second video in the tweet shows the seal is turning itself in the water few times in the same position, which may be mistaken for "I am drowning" act.

One of the users (TTu) replied with another possibility of "I am itchy" act, to which the original poster (OP) shared some laugh:

> TTu: 痒いのでわ‼︎
>   OP: なるほどですww

Note that the usernames have been replaced with relevant placeholders, which are otherwise not important to understand their conversations about the posted video.